# Generate a DOC for a REST API

Tags: php, api, documentation, documentation-generation

I have generated my REST API, and now I have to write a documentation for the API.

As the API is mainly generated by a third-party plugin it's not possible to generate the DOC automatically.

**So what the best tool (to save time) to *manually* write a DOC?**

PS: I do have github account, I wonder if the user pages can fit this need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can spent sometime to put **DocBlock** into all function/class you have built

A tool like [PHPDOC](http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_phpDocumentor.howto.pkg.html) is available for you to compile DocBlock into documentation and regenerate whatever you need (into your desired format).

Not to mention, is stored as static HTML

Comment: phpDocumentor is not a tool for writing documentation for API exposed over RESTful services. It can only be used in order to generate documentation for your classes and methods, but not for your RESTful service.

Comment: Dude,read the php description http://www.phpdoc.org/

Comment: Can you give me an example URL to justify the time you suggest on spending for reading the whole documentation?

Comment: i dun know how extensive of the rest structure you are so particular about, definitely u aren't looking into the details of the existing @api option - http://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/for-users/phpdoc/tags/api.html

Comment: and dun misleading by the title -- OP is just looking for a tool that can generate DOCs for him

Comment: IMHO he is looking for a way to autogenerate most of the documentation needed for documenting his own RESTful services. Here's an example how one of these should look like: http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/call

Comment: No, `As the API is mainly generated by a third-party plugin it's not possible to generate the DOC automatically.`

Comment: Anyway, you are not helping him as phpDocumentor is not suitable for documenting RESTful services :)

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at [TechWriter for Web Services](http://www.adivo.com/techwriter-for-web-services.aspx).  It also supports generating documentation for REST APIs.